# how i can create my own CCTexture2D copying a piece of another CCTexture2D

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, textures, texture2d

I found how to repat single image to make a fitting background for my level:

```
[self setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR,GL_LINEAR,GL_REPEAT,GL_REPEAT};
[self.texture setTexParameters:&params];
```

the problem is I must use a single.png image, and not a spritesheet.png + .plist file.

This because when i do `[self setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)]` for set my repeated background width, if the image is a spritesheet cocos2d take the other sprites in the spritesheet repeating and not only my background sprite.

The question is: how i can create my own texture coping a piece of another texture??

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the issue:
[Link to cocos2d forum question](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/16029?replies=8#post-90754)